# Dialog Box in R

Tags: r, dialog

I'm trying to create a dialog box that pops up and asks the user for their email address and then stores that in a variable.

I tried using the 'tcltk' package, but I can't install in on my new version. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: Could you please post the relevant code?

Comment: Why can't you install the package? Have you tried downloading the package along with its dependencies and putting them in the correct directory under your R version?

Answer (score 0):

I've just released the R bindings for [tinyfiledialogs](http://tinyfiledialogs.sourceforge.net) v3.14.
It offers many modal dialogs and popup notifications (both for graphic and console modes). It is cross-platform C (windows, Mac, Unix) and aims to be extremely easy to use. There is no init, no main loop, and no external dependencies. It is used by hundreds of projects on GitHub.

```
# first load the included library
dyn.load("tinyfiledialogsLinux64.so")

# then load the included R interface
tinyfd_openFileDialog <- function(aTitle, aDefaultPathAndFile , aNumOfFilterPatterns,
        aFilterPatterns, aSingleFilterDescription , aAllowMultipleSelects)
{
  result <- .C("tfd_openFileDialog",
        charToRaw(aTitle),
        lOpenFile = aDefaultPathAndFile ,
        as.integer(aNumOfFilterPatterns) ,
        aFilterPatterns ,
        charToRaw(aSingleFilterDescription) ,
        as.integer(aAllowMultipleSelects) )

  if ( result$lOpenFile == "NULL" ) return()
  else return(result$lOpenFile)
}

# now, you can call the dialog
lFilename <- tinyfd_openFileDialog( "a title" , "/Users/bardos/Documents/" , 1 , c ("*.txt","*.jpg") , "some files" , 0 )
```